# How to sort Querylist in django ( rest api )

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

```
class AllStudioListConsoleViewset(FlatMultipleModelAPIView):

    def get_querylist(self):
        user = self.request.query_params['user'].replace('-', ' ')
        print(user)
        querylist = [
            {
                'queryset': audio_details.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-created_on'),
                'serializer_class': AudioStudioListConsoleSerializers,
                'label': 'audio',
            },
            {
                'queryset': VideoStudioDetails.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-created_on'),
                'serializer_class': VideoStudioListConsoleSerializers,
                'label': 'video'
            },
            {
                'queryset': ShootStudioDetails.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-created_on'),
                'serializer_class': ShootStudioListConsoleSerializers,
                'label': 'video'
            },
        ]
        return querylist
```

**How to sort all querylist `created_on`**

Comment: I think the only possibility is to override the corresponding methods such as get/post/put etc

Answer (score 0):

```
class TextAPIView(FlatMultipleModelAPIView):
    sorting_fields = ['title']

    querylist = [
        {'queryset': Play.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': PlaySerializer},
        {'queryset': Poem.objects.filter(style='Sonnet'), 'serializer_class': PoemSerializer},
        ....
    ]
```

For more information: https://django-rest-multiple-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flat-options.html